# Can't get Android WebView's postUrl to work with a port

Tags: java, android, webview, android-webview

My WebView is working perfectly until I add in a port.  At which point I don't see any sort of error and I see nothing in my HTTP traffic.

```
private Context vContext;
private String vPackageName;
private String vPlacementID;

static private double TRACK_VERSION = 1.0;
static private String TRACK_HOST = "foobar.com:8007";
static private String TRACK_HANDLER = "/event";

public void reportAppOpen(Context context, String placementID) {
    Log.d("FOO", "Tracking");
    if (context == null) {
        return;
    }
    vContext = context;
    vPackageName = vContext.getPackageName();
    vPlacementID = placementID;

    WebView webview = new WebView(context);
    webview.setVisibility(WebView.GONE);
    webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
                Log.d("FOO", "error code:" + errorCode);
                super.onReceivedError(view, errorCode, description, failingUrl);
        }
     });
    webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    List<NameValuePair> params = trackingParams();
    String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
    String url = "http://" + TRACK_HOST + TRACK_HANDLER;
    webview.postUrl(url, EncodingUtils.getBytes(paramString, "base64"));

    Log.d("FOO", "Loading URL");        
}
```

I know there is some other weird stuff going on in my code but for now I'd like to just focus on getting `postUrl` to work.

EDIT:  In the logcat I found this not sure if it is relevant.

```
10-19 13:44:21.560: D/SntpClient(59): request time failed: java.net.SocketException: Address family not supported by protocol
```

Comment: are you getting anything in the logcat?

Comment: I found `10-19 13:44:21.560: D/SntpClient(59): request time failed: java.net.SocketException: Address family not supported by protocol`.  Looking it up seems like it thinks the uri is invalid maybe?  But the url is clearly valid unless there is some otherway to pass the port.

Comment: that is SntpClient error not related to your app..

Answer (score 1):

Please try with WebChromeClient and override following methods:

```
   @Override
public void onConsoleMessage(String message, int lineNumber, String sourceID) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Log.v("ChromeClient", "invoked: onConsoleMessage() - " + sourceID + ":"
            + lineNumber + " - " + message);
    super.onConsoleMessage(message, lineNumber, sourceID);
}

@Override
public boolean onConsoleMessage(ConsoleMessage cm) {
    Log.v("ChromeClient", cm.message() + " -- From line "
            + cm.lineNumber() + " of "
            + cm.sourceId() );
    return true;
}
```

to debug the issue..

Comment: looks like you're overloading onConsoleMessage twice.

Comment: onConsoleMessage(String message, int lineNumber, String sourceID) is now deprecated..